# Equivalent of -P in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When running a container the `-P` command automatically maps the exposed ports to a random port on host machine.  How can I get this same behaviour with `docker-compose` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose doesn't support auto publishing all exposed ports in the image.

The [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) service configuration does support specifying just container port, or port range, which will then pick a random port to publish as on the host. You will need to maintain the list of container ports to do that for in Compose though.

```
services:
  web:
    image: whatever
    ports:
      - "3000"
```